# Java Datanucleus - create database on startup

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I searched the docs and web for it and could not find the answer.
I'm trying to create a mysql db from datanucleus on startup, I don't mean the CreateSchema option but the `create database` command.

Is there an option to do it rather then from the mysql server ?

I'm using datanucleus 4.1,

Thanks .

Comment: There is no way to create the database automatically with DN. The database must exist.